# How to convert STRING_TOO_LARGE string in json object android

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I am trying to convert string to JSON object but it's not working I keep getting `STRING_TOO_LARGE` error

this is my [Json1](https://github.com/xomena-so/so41431384/blob/master/app/src/main/res/raw/es_geojson.json) and  [2](https://github.com/xomena-so/so41431384/blob/master/app/src/main/res/raw/us_geojson.json) file which I am trying to convert to show layer over google map
I am doing something like this

```
val json2Object = JSONObject(getString(R.string.json_data))
```

please help me how do I achieve this

Comment: Did you tried to use Kotlin Serialization, Gson, Moshi or Jackson instead of vanilla JSONObject?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization like this:

```
@Serializable
class EsGeoJson (
    val type: String
    /*... describe all fields here */
)

val obj = Json.decodeFromString<EsGeoJson>(Constants.jsonData)
```

Comment: the problem is that I don't have a model EsGeoJson  for this. the response would be dynamic if i have model then i can done using Gson also

Comment: every country JSON will be different so using model not possible

Comment: You still can use it like this: class EsGeoJson (val type: String, val dynamicData: Object). And then cast dynamicData to list or map or whatever it is.

Comment: At least I'm deeply convinced that it's possible with Gson. @ChiragPatel

Comment: val convertedObject: JsonObject = Gson().fromJson(getString(R.string.json_data), JsonObject::class.java)

Comment: i am trying something like this but not working because of string_too_large